# Looking for free and easy that (auto) generates JUnit tests

Tags: java, junit

Can I get recommendations of free and easy tool(s) that can generate JUnit tests based on existing code?

Either as a stand-alone application or pref. an Eclipse-plugin.

Comment: I suppose guys who would make that tool could earn a lot of money having a tool which writes code.

Comment: All I can do, it to strongly advise you to back off from this approach. There are tools out there that auto-generate JUnit tests, (most are not free), but it comes with the cost of unmaintainable test code.

Comment: There are a whole bunch of code generators at http://www.junit.org/taxonomy/term/7 - but why would it be bad to use them? I want to like to rightclick on a method and create some basic junit-code, nothing fancy

Comment: One of the problem with these tools is that it generates tests based on the actual behavior of the code - the tests are not on the desired contract. That is, if you have a bogus code, the generated test will reflect the implemented bogus behavior. Then when you change (fix) the code, the tests fail. These tools are basically only good for legacy code test coverage, and even this is controversial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, depends on what do you need your tests for...
If just to have tests coverage and basic behavior tested - then yes, use can use test generators.
If you are serious about the project and plan to expend it, see the future of the project - then it would be really better to create good unit tests in traditional way.